# PL/SQL inheritance implementation where procedure is implemented under the sub object

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

Entity Relationship Diagram

[image]

The problem is

> Given the inheritance hierarchy depicted in the vehicles object model find solution for the following questions
>   1. Identify the appropriate object types and implement the vehicle inheritance type hierarchy
>   2. The get_vehicle member function returns the complete information of the appropriate vehicles type
>   3. set_gear_count member procedure takes two parameters the gear_count and the vehicle id and updates a bicycle gear_count.
>   4. Create anonymous PLSQL block and instantiate truck and bicycle instances and insert them in the appropriate table. Then demonstrate the use of get_vechile and set_gear_count member methods.

For this problem I wrote the following PL/SQL but I  am getting the following error

```
SQL> @inheritance;

Warning: Type Body created with compilation errors.
```

The error occurs when I try to run the `CREATE TYPE BODY bicycle AS` body and the specific area of the error is `set_gear_count` procedure.

```
SQL> show error
Errors for TYPE BODY BICYCLE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
10/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/13    PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
SQL>
```

The code I wrote is the following

```
--creating the base vehicle object type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE vehicle_t AS OBJECT
(
vehicle_id NUMBER,
manufacturer VARCHAR2(30),
purchase_date DATE,
color VARCHAR2 (10),
MEMBER FUNCTION get_vehicle RETURN VARCHAR2
)NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE TYPE BODY vehicle_t AS
MEMBER FUNCTION get_vehicle RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
BEGIN
RETURN 'Vehicle ID:'|| TO_CHAR (vehicle_id) || 'Manufacturer:'|| manufacturer || 'Purchase Date:'||purchase_date||'Color:'||color;
END get_vehicle;
END;
/

-- CREATING SUB TYPE OF VEHICLE_T POWERED_VEHICLE  
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE powred_vehicle UNDER vehicle_t
(
fule_type VARCHAR2(30),
license_number VARCHAR2 (10),
model VARCHAR2 (10),
OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION get_vehicle RETURN VARCHAR2
)FINAL;
/

CREATE TYPE BODY powred_vehicle AS
OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION get_vehicle RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
BEGIN
RETURN (self AS vehicle_t).get_vehicle || 'Fuel Type:'|| fule_type || 'License Number:'||license_number||'Model:'||model;
END get_vehicle;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE bicycle UNDER vehicle_t
(
gear_count number,
OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION get_vehicle RETURN VARCHAR2,
MEMBER PROCEDURE set_gear_count (p_gear_count IN bicycle, p_vehicleid IN vehicle_t)
)FINAL;
/


CREATE TABLE vehicle_tab OF bicycle;
```

This is where the error occurs.

```
CREATE TYPE BODY bicycle AS
OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION get_vehicle RETURN VARCHAR2
IS 
BEGIN
RETURN (self AS vehicle_t).get_vehicle || 'Gear Count:'|| TO_CHAR(gear_count);
END get_vehicle;
MEMBER PROCEDURE set_gear_count (p_gear_count IN bicycle, p_vehicleid IN vehicle_t)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO vehicle_tab VALUES (p_gear_count, p_vehicleid);
END set_gear_count;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

I seems vehicle_tab is a table of bicycle.  I think you want to do this?

```
INSERT INTO vehicle_tab VALUES (SELF);
```

Also, I think it is confusing that p_gear_count is of type bicycle: shouldn't it be a number of some kind?